# list assignment index out of range

Tags: python, python-2.7, lista

Uma parte do meu programa em Python é:

```
dt=1
maxt=3600*2
t=range(0,maxt,dt)
r=len(t)
Tsup_i=20

for i in range(1,r):
    Tsup[0]=Tsup_i
    P[i]=((I_dc)**2) * R20 * (1 + a * (Tsup[i] - (20+K)))
```

E está a aparecer o erro

> "IndexError: list assignment index out of range"

Na linha correspondente a `Tsup[0]=Tsup_i` e eu não sei como resolver...

O `Tsup` eu coloquei antes do ciclo `for` como sendo uma lista vazia `Tsup=[]`, e o que pretendo é que o 1º elemento da lista seja igual a `Tsup_i`, que dê para determinar `P[i]` e mais à frente no código consiga determinar `Tsup[i+1]` usando `P[i]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Tsup` é uma lista vazia e você tenta acessar o seu primeiro elemento fazendo `Tsup[0]`. Para associar um novo elemento a ela o correto é usa a função `append()`:

```
Tsup.append(Tsup_i)
```

Mas se atente que dentro do `for` ele vai adicionar um elemento novo para cada iteração, criando `Tsup[0]`, `Tsup[1]`, .... até `Tsup[r]`. Se você quiser que associar apenas ao primeiro elemento você pode fazer isso fora do seu ciclo `for`.

Comment: ok, fiz isso, ficaria então:

dt=1
maxt=3600*2
t=range(0,maxt,dt)
r=len(t)
Tsup_i=20
Tsup=[]
P=[]
 for i in range(1,r): 
        Tsup.append(Tsup_inicial)

        P[i]=((I_dc)**2) * R20 * (1 + a * (Tsup[i] - (20+K)))
        P.append(P[i])

mas depois dá o erro: "IndexError: list index out of range" em "P[i]=((I_dc)**2) * R20 * (1 + a * (Tsup[i] - (20+K)))"

Comment: Não consigo ter certeza da parte lógica, mas da parte de sintaxe o erro em `Tsup` está corrigido sim, agora tem que fazer o mesmo para o `P`, assim: `P.append()`. Feito isso é bem possível que corrija os erros de sintaxe, daí tem que ver se o resultado é o esperado.

Comment: Fiz isso e continua a dar erro:

P.append(((I_dc)**2) * R20 * (1 + a * (Tsup[i] - (20+K))))

"IndexError: list index out of range" nesta , mesma linha

Comment: Ah sim, agora eu vi, vc está fazendo `Tsup[i]` e vc acaba tentando acessar uma posição do `Tsup`  que não existe, talvez fosse o caso de vc fazer `range(0, r)`. Se isso não resolver acho que vai ter que postar mais partes do seu código para eu entender o que está tetando fazer e ajudar a refatorar o seu código.

Comment: Muito obrigado! Aparentemente este problema está resolvido.
Agora surgiu-me outro. Depois do código anterior, tenho esta parte:

if i==r: 
       Te=(((P[i]+Ps-Pc[i]-Pr[i])*(dt))/((m_al*c_al[i])+(m_a*c_a[i])))+Tsup[i]
e dá-me um erro que diz: "NameError: name 'Te' is not defined".

Onde as variaveis: P[i], Ps, Pc[i], Pr[i], m_al, c_al[i] são calculadas anteriormente sem problema.
O que eu quero dizer é que Te é o valor correspondente à ultima posição da lista, ou seja, quando i=r. E como Te é suposto ser 1 só valor e não uma lista de valores, achei que nãotinha que inicializá-lo antes

Comment: Não consegui entender muito bem o problema, até mesmo porque na área dos comentários fica difícil visualizar. Sugiro que você crie uma pergunta nova explicando esse problema até mesmo para manter a organização do site, separando uma dúvida por tópico. E caso essa resposta respondeu a sua dúvida sugiro que considere marcá-la como aceita, clicando na marca de verificação (V) ao lado dela.